# Declare struct in class Perl

Tags: perl, struct

I want declare struct in of mi class in perl.In case anyone does not know this module: http://perldoc.perl.org/Class/Struct.html
And this is my code:

```
package object;
sub new{
    my $class = shift;
    struct( 'object', { hashMap => '%', array => '@' });
    my $self = {
        'object::hashMap' => shift ,
        'object::array' => shift ,
        _toret => shift // 0,
    };
    $self->{_toret} = new object;
    return bless $self, $class;    
}
```

if i want get my hasMap from struct, i should a object to call this 
 struct, but I don't want to declare it in a function, because i would 
 lose the data every time I refer the function.And that's why I declare it in class. The problem is that when i do the function, to get the hasMap this gives me error and tells me that it cann´t be referenced to hashMap

```
sub get{
        my($self) =@_;
        return $self->{_toret}->hashMap;
    }
```

i hope that you can help me. thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by `$self->{_toret} => new object;`? Did you mean `=` instead?

Comment: Calling `new object` from `object::new` smells like infinite recursion.

Comment: ohh yes !! is $self->{_toret} = new object; it´s a mistake, but still fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating this massively. The `struct()` function should be called from within the top-level package code, not from within the constructor (calling `struct()` creates a constructor called `new()` for you). And calling `new()` from within `new()` seems like a recipe for disaster.

You've described what doesn't work, but you haven't really described what you're trying to achieve. I think that you want this (but, without more details, I really can't be sure).

```
# Object is a terrible name for a class.
# But if you insist on using it, at least capitalise the name.
# Lowercase names are reserved for pragmata in Perl.
package Object;

use Class::Struct;

struct( hashMap => '%', array => '@' );

1;
```

You can then use your class like this:

```
use Object;

my $obj = Object->new(
  hashMap => { foo => 1, bar => 2, baz => 3},
  array   => [ 0 .. 10]
);

say $obj->hashMap->{foo}; # prints 1
say $obj->array->[10];    # prints 10
```

If that's not what you want, you need to explain a lot more about what you are trying to do.